# DeleteFile, C++, WinCE

Tags: c++, windows-ce, delete-file, evc4

Whats wrong about this?

```
if((
::DeleteFile( L"IO.res"))== NULL)
MessageBox(NULL,L"Error",L"OK",MB_OK);
```

I have the IO.res file in the same directory, but the program cant delete it.
With the integrated File manager I can delete.
I use EVC4.

Comment: What is the value of `GetLastError()` immediately after `DeleteFile` returns?  Also, you should be comparing the return value with 0, not `NULL` -- it returns `BOOL`, not a pointer type.

Comment: I dont know what is the return value of the GetLastError, because its dont want working: if((
  

 ::DeleteFile( L"IO.res"))== 0)
 DWORD error;
 error=GetLastError();
 MessageBox(NULL,error,L"OK",MB_OK);

Comment: I fixed the NULL to 0. But the IO.res still exist.

Comment: Try this instead to get the error: `if(DeleteFile(L"IO.res") == 0) { wchar_t buffer[256]; _snwprintf(buffer, 256, "Delete file failed with error %d", GetLastError()); MessageBox(NULL, buffer, L"Error", MB_OK); }`

Comment: error C2664: '_snwprintf' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char [33]' to 'const unsigned short *'

Comment: Y'know, I try to be helpful, but I'm not going to handhold you through everything.  I made a slight mistake in that code fragment, but you really ought to be able to fix that yourself.

Comment: Ok, fixed. The GetLastError() value is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows CE doesn't have any concept of a "current" or "working" directory.  You must provide a fully qualified path to the file you want to delete.

Comment: I tried with specified directory but the problem is the same.

Comment: The we need the *exact* code you ran and the result from GetLastError.  Using the debugger you should be able to get the value without printing it out.  Use the Locals window.

Comment: Solved! The problem is really to need specify the foldername! First time Im wrong when I give the file path. Now its working! Thanks a lot to ctacke and Adam Rosenfield, and sorry about the newbie questions.